# Jasmine creation of queries

Tags: javascript, api, jasmine

Hello I'm new using jasmine, and I'm not sure of how to build a mock all the tutorials that i found are base on angular or other frame work but I'm working with knex and query builder to create queries but I'm no sure how to create a mock using jasmine, so I was wondering if you guys can give me some examples of how mocking queries using jasmine or know a good tutorial that explains that (be sides the jasmine docs). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create mocks with Jasmine, refer here to method `jasmine.createSpyObj`: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_`createSpyObj`

If you need more sophisticated mocks I would suggest Sinon.js: http://sinonjs.org/ 
Both can be used together. You can for instance mock Ajax, servers and timers in a more convenient way